# Notebook only works without Hard Disk

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, laptop, hardware-failure

i'm having some troubles with an old Toshiba notebook.
Like 2 months ago it stopped working and it only loads the BIOS and then nothing happens.
I tried formatting it, but the same happens, it doesn't matter wich OS i use, it just don't start.
But if i remove the HDD and start the Notebook from a live USB it works. I already tried ElementaryOS, Damn Small Linux and Puppy Linux without a problem.
I also tried installing ElementaryOS and Windows 7 in the HDD with another notebook, and it worked without a problem, but if i put it in the Toshiba Notebook, the PC didn't work.
I need to know what could the problem with the Notebook, because it's working, and i would like to use it with Windows, and if it isn't possible, a Linux distribution like Debian or ElementaryOS, because Puppy and DSL are good options, but not very functional for my needs.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried a different HDD?

Comment: The only HDD that i have is the primary disk of another notebook, so i'm not sure if is safe to plug the HDD to the other notebook. The main reason to find the problem with the old notebook is because i don't want to spend money for no reason, because if the problem could be the MB or the CPU i'll use it with Puppy or something similar until it just "die". Is it safe to plug the HDD of the other Notebook to the old one? Can i lose some data?

Comment: As far as I know, it's perfectly fine to plug another HD into your computer. It may experience some weird stuff once the OS is all loaded and logged into, but for your purposes you should be able to use it to diagnose.

Comment: Check the disk cable - both sides, and the entire length. Particularly for signs of mechanical damage. Also check if, with the disk connected, the BIOS reports the correct disk info. If the info is not there, it's quite likely to be a power or cable problem. If the info is not correct, check if the BIOS has a detection routine. It might be configured with the wrong drive.

Comment: I tried replacing the HDD for another one from my primary computer and it worked. What could be the problem? Because the old HDD worked on the primary notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's old, it might be a battery problem... though I don't know why a dead CMOS battery should cause HDD issues in particular, the battery is needed for the system clock and sometimes BIOS RAM. Please let us know if that is the issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the help. I'll try today all the solutions and then i'll post the results here. I had some troubles with the BIOS battery before with another PC, but it just don't show anything when i power it on, so i think is not a battery issue, because it loads the BIOS, but i'll try the solution in either way.